# After jquery UI dialog close, postback on entire page doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i open UI dialog in this way:

```
var $dialog = jQuery('#dialog');    
     $dialog.load('mySite.aspx');
     $dialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Add New Contact Personel',
        modal: true,
        height: 350,
        width: 400,
        show: 'puff',
        hide: 'puff',
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $dialog.html('');
            $dialog.dialog('destroy');
        }
     });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
```

and after i close this using cross in right upper corent, all others buttons not connected to UI dialog doesn't work, for example linkButton in gridview below lost his meaning, in firefox does't work, in chrom redirect to page which preavious UI dialog used, but when i refresh the page, everything seems to work fine untill i click again to open UI dialog, then all others links doesn't work again.

```
<asp:GridView ID="userGridView" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            GridLines="None"
            AllowPaging="true"
            DataKeyNames="UserId"
            OnRowCommand="UserGridViewRowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" Visible="false"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" HeaderStyle-Width="75px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                         <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="ChartLinkBtn" ToolTip="go to EAS (user page)" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserId") %>' CommandName="User" runat="server"><img src="../Styles/icons/chart.png" style="border:0px" alt="text"/></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteLinkBtn" ToolTip="delete this user" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserId") %>' CommandName="Delete" runat="server"><img src="../Styles/icons/delete.png" style="border:0px" alt="text"/></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: no, in firefox is just nothing, all links simple doesn't work, like there were unclickable, in chrom each link open previous content of UI dialog

Comment: do you have a reference to jquery in mySite.aspx - I have seen instances where referencing a new copy of jquery within a dialog content, removes all existing events.

Comment: no for 100% i don't have, my main page reference from master page and this mySite.aspx not, this is simple aspx page.

Comment: doesn't work everythink which looks like this: href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$userGridView$ctl02$DeleteLinkBtn','')"

Comment: ok so this is problem of second scriptManager on mySite.aspx which is loaded by UI dialog, but now i am really confused, i need to use updatePanel there, but if remove ScriptManager updatePanel doesn't show it's content, the same is if i replace ScriptManager to ScriptManagerProxy

Comment: How about if you use $dialog.dialog('close'); instead of 'destroy' when the dialog is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is any help, why not force the full-postback altogether?

```
close: function (event, ui) {
        $dialog.html('');
        $dialog.dialog('destroy');
        __doPostBack(); //to perform a full postback
    }
```

or try this (put this within the javascript tags) ...

```
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (evt, args) {
    var myDiv = $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    }
    });
});
```

cheers!